# System.Threading.ThreadAbortException from AWSSDK for .net

Tags: aws-sdk

I am getting this weird exception in my code. It is with VS 2015, .net 4.6, and AWSSDK Nuget Package. This is being thrown while running unit test locally.

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException occurred
  HResult=-2146233040
  Message=Thread was being aborted.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, UInt32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
       at System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, Int64 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
       at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean exitContext)
       at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne()
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.BackgroundDispatcher`1.Run() in d:\Jenkins\workspace\build-sdkandtools\sdk\src\AWSSDK_DotNet35\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Util\Dispatcher.cs:line 147
  InnerException:
```

Anyone has this before? How could i prevent this from happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error when using AWSSDK for .NET, specifically `AWSSDK.CloudSearchDomain v3.1.0.6`. In my case, the error appeared to be raised when calls to AWSSDK `*Async` methods were made inside a C# `Parallel.Foreach` statement. Specifically, this failed on the call to `UploadDocumentsAsync` with a thread abort:

```
Parallel.ForEach<AttachmentObject>(files, async file => {
  ...
  var request = new Amazon.CloudSearchDomain.Model.UploadDocumentsRequest() {...}
  var response = await client.UploadDocumentsAsync(request);
});
```

while this succeeded:

```
foreach (var file in files) {
  ...
  var request = new Amazon.CloudSearchDomain.Model.UploadDocumentsRequest() {...}
  var response = await client.UploadDocumentsAsync(request);
};
```